# Nestjs "Reference Error: File is not defined" only in test

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, nrwl-nx

My test suite is failing to run because the "File" input type is undefined. This only happens when trying to run tests. The app works perfectly in development. Below is my console output.

```
$ nx run build-support-cases-api-core:test

> nx run build-support-cases-api-core:test 
 FAIL   build-support-cases-api-core  libs/build-support-cases/api/core/src/lib/__test__/buildSupportCase.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: File is not defined

      4 | export class CreateReceiptInput {
      5 |   @Field(() => String)
    > 6 |   public receipt: File;
        |                   ^
      7 |
      8 |   @Field(() => String)
      9 |   public vendorName: string;

      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../core/database/receipt/src/lib/dto/createReceipt.input.ts:6:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../core/database/receipt/src/lib/dto/createReceipt.dto.ts:1:1)
```

Here is the full source file for completeness

```
import { Field, ID, InputType } from "@nestjs/graphql";

@InputType()
export class CreateReceiptInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  public receipt: File;

  @Field(() => String)
  public vendorName: string;

  @Field(() => Date)
  public purchaseDate: Date;

  @Field(() => Number)
  public totalDollarAmount: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  public purchasedBy: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  public note: string;

  @Field(() => ID)
  public updateId?: number;
}
```

Is there something in a config file somewhere that I am missing? How do I get past this issue so that my tests will run?

Comment: Where does `File` usually come from? What does it represent?

Comment: From the description, it is an interface that provides information about files and allows JavaScript in a web page to access their content. It comes from typescript. https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.file.html

Comment: Okay, what does it represent though? It looks like that type comes from the `lib` types, which `ts-jest` is probably throwing out during type checking. You should probably have a dedicated type for that that doesn't come from `lib` (front end types)

Comment: It represents the input type of the CreateReceiptInput receipt method. I am posting an object of type CreateReceiptInput to my ReceiptService, where I upload the file to aws and save the url it uploaded to into my database. You are right that File is a front end type as it comes from FormData. Is there a different way I should be handling this?

Comment: You did not import `File`. It is an interface, which is defined somewhere else. So you have to import it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that File exists in typescript but not within NodeJS, (or NestJS by extension). However, the Blob type does exist in NestJS so the File type defined by typescript works if you just copy it over to a new file and import it.

```
export interface File extends Blob {
  readonly lastModified: number;
  readonly name: string;
}
```

```
import { Field, ID, InputType } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { File } from "./interfaces";
@InputType()
export class CreateReceiptInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  public receipt: File;

  @Field(() => String)
  public vendorName: string;

  @Field(() => Date)
  public purchaseDate: Date;

  @Field(() => Number)
  public totalDollarAmount: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  public purchasedBy: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  public note: string;

  @Field(() => ID)
  public updateId?: number;
}
```